# How does one process see the write of another process immediately?

Tags: linux, operating-system

I wrote a program where one process writes data to a file and another process reads the data from the same file. Pseudo codes are below:

```
write process:
    1. open file;
    2. write data to file;
    3. set true to flag;
    4. sleep infinity;

read process:
    1. open file;
    2. loop inifinity:
    3.   if flag:
    4.     read data from file;
```

I know how the writing of a file works in os:

```
buffered file | unbuffered file
--- | flush ------- | write ---
    V               V
          os kernel
------------- | sync ----------
              V
            disk
```

So I divide my question into three concrete questions:

- In step 2 of write process, if I flush the buffered file (or directly write unbuffered file) into os kernel, can read process see the data immediately after write process sets the flag?
- in step 2 of write process, if I sync the data in file from os kernel into disk, can read process see the data immediately after write process sets the flag?
- If I replace process with thread, is the result will be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to all three questions is that yes, every time you perform a `read(2)` after a `write(2)`, the data is guaranteed to be visible.  From POSIX 1003.1-2008:

> If a `read()` of file data can be proven (by any means) to occur after a `write()` of the data, it must reflect that `write()`, even if the calls are made by different processes.

This does require a POSIX-conformant file system; as the Linux manual pages note, not all file systems are POSIX conformant.  POSIX also requires this behavior of `pwrite(2)` and `writev(2)`, since they are defined as being “equivalent to `write()`” with specified exceptions.

In your case, it also assumes that your buffered file calls `write(2)` (or one of the other relevant functions) under the hood; I believe this is true of glibc's stdio library.

Comment: Thank you. I find the [reference](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) by your answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the write system call for writing data, the other process or thread should see it immediately. Since it is a running system, it should not matter whether the data is in the buffer cache or actually written to the hard disk. However, if you use the standard library call like fwrite, there is the problem of data getting bufferred in the process and the other process not seeing it immediately. So, avoid libraries and use the write system call directly. Only when there is the risk of system crash, one has to worry about actually writing to the hard disk for every write operation with synchronized I/O using the O_DSYNC or O_SYNC flag in the write call.